# How can I bundle a bunch of installations binaries together into one executable that calls a bunch of sub-executables?

Tags: windows-installer, installation-package, win32

I have a script which I want to deploy to some people in my group, but there are three dependencies ( python2.7, ExchangeCDO, pywin32).  Is there a way that I can create *one* installation file that has these three installation dependencies bundled into exactly one file?  e.g. an `.exe` or an `.msi`.

Comment: Why is someone wanting to close this question?  Is it a duplicate?  If so, point me to the other ticket.  What is your feedback, drive-by closer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done something similar before by using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). NSIS (Nullsoft Install System) is an open-source installation wizard tool. You can easily create a bundled installer which includes and runs all of your dependencies. For example, the installer for Firefox (and many other projects) uses NSIS.

Comment: Another good application for this is [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). I have used both and they each have their strengths and weaknesses. When I tried them last (3 years ago) Inno Setups Wizard mode was a bit better but NSIS was easier to do more advanced stuff in.